# go clean -i -r tries to remove /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime.a

Tags: go

This is kinda odd. When i try to to "go clean -i -r" go tries (permissions) to remove runtime.a.
Is this normal? :

```
go clean -i -x
cd /home/gotestprojects/src/simplehelloworld
rm -f simplehelloworld.test simplehelloworld.test.exe
rm -f /home/gotestprojects/pkg/linux_amd64/simplehelloworld.a

go clean -r -x
cd /home/gotestprojects/src/simplehelloworld
rm -f simplehelloworld.test simplehelloworld.test.exe
cd /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime
rm -f runtime.test runtime.test.exe defs1_linux defs1_linux.exe defs2_linux defs2_linux.exe defs_arm_linux defs_arm_linux.exe defs_darwin defs_darwin.exe defs_dragonfly defs_dragonfly.exe defs_freebsd defs_freebsd.exe defs_linux defs_linux.exe defs_netbsd defs_netbsd.exe defs_netbsd_386 defs_netbsd_386.exe defs_netbsd_amd64 defs_netbsd_amd64.exe defs_netbsd_arm defs_netbsd_arm.exe defs_openbsd defs_openbsd.exe defs_windows defs_windows.exe malloc1 malloc1.exe mallocrand mallocrand.exe mallocrep mallocrep.exe mallocrep1 mallocrep1.exe race race.exe syscall_windows_test syscall_windows_test.exe vlop_arm_test vlop_arm_test.exe
cd /usr/local/go/src/pkg/unsafe
rm -f unsafe.test unsafe.test.exe
```

And now the error :

```
go clean -i -r -x
cd /home/gotestprojects/src/simplehelloworld
rm -f simplehelloworld.test simplehelloworld.test.exe
rm -f /home/gotestprojects/pkg/linux_amd64/simplehelloworld.a
cd /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime
rm -f runtime.test runtime.test.exe defs1_linux defs1_linux.exe defs2_linux defs2_linux.exe defs_arm_linux defs_arm_linux.exe defs_darwin defs_darwin.exe defs_dragonfly defs_dragonfly.exe defs_freebsd defs_freebsd.exe defs_linux defs_linux.exe defs_netbsd defs_netbsd.exe defs_netbsd_386 defs_netbsd_386.exe defs_netbsd_amd64 defs_netbsd_amd64.exe defs_netbsd_arm defs_netbsd_arm.exe defs_openbsd defs_openbsd.exe defs_windows defs_windows.exe malloc1 malloc1.exe mallocrand mallocrand.exe mallocrep mallocrep.exe mallocrep1 mallocrep1.exe race race.exe syscall_windows_test syscall_windows_test.exe vlop_arm_test vlop_arm_test.exe
rm -f /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime.a
go clean: remove /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime.a: permission denied
cd /usr/local/go/src/pkg/unsafe
rm -f unsafe.test unsafe.test.exe
```

Maybe something i dont understand ?

Comment: Strange. That reminds me of https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6424.

Comment: can you paste the output of `go env` please?

Comment: Here you go : GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/gotestprojects/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: Could you try again, without setting GOROOT? (as in http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really)

Comment: @VonC: `go env` always shows the effective GOROOT, even though it's not set (and it's usually "/usr/local/go").

Comment: @JimB Indeed, I belatedly realized that by re-reading the link I mentioned above!

Comment: $GOROOT is not set. Its /usr/local/go by default. echo $GOROOT gives empty response. I know that's odd...You only set $GOROOT if you use custom path to go (from golang docs).